# How to get number of values in each row of a sparse tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a Sparse Tensor as follows:

```
st = tf.sparse.from_dense([[1, 0, 2, 5], [3, 0, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 2, 2]])
print(st)
```

```
SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
[[0 0]
 [0 2]
 [0 3]
 [1 0]
 [1 3]
 [3 0]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [4 0]
 [4 1]
 [4 2]
 [4 3]], shape=(12, 2), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([1 2 5 3 4 1 1 3 1 2 2 2], shape=(12,), dtype=int32), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([5 4], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

I want to convert this sparse tensor to another 1D tensor of shape `(5, 1)` where the only column represents the number (or size) of values in each of the rows.

For example, for the above sparse tensor, desired 1D tensor would be `[3, 2, 0, 3, 4]`.

How can I do it?

I tried going through the TensorFlow API docs but couldn't find anything to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bin count` on the indices.

```
tf.math.bincount(tf.cast(st.indices[:,0], tf.int32))
```